# Error: Invalid value of type object for mergeProps argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm setting up my app with redux, and i'm new to it. I want to make `onClick()` event to take **item's id** but im getting error.

I searched a lot of answers here, but they didn't help me a lot.
Documentation says, that i'm not connecting my action right, but I found no good explanation, only example with toDo, which is not enough for me.

**Products.js**(where I want my `onClick()`)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navbar from "../navbar/Navbar";
import Product from "../lists/Product";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getItems } from "../../actions/getItems";
import { getDetails } from "../../actions/getDetails";

class Products extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid products">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="title display-3 text-center pt-2">
            <b>Our Products</b>
          </h1>
          <div className="underline" />
          <div className="py-5">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                {this.props.shopItems.items.map(item => {
                  return (
                    <div
                      onClick={() =>this.props.getDetails(item.id)}
                      className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-9"
                      key={item.id}
                    >
                      <div className="card-deck">
                        <Product
                          name={item.name}
                          brand={item.brand}
                          img={item.img}
                          price={item.price}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Products.propTypes = {
  shopItems: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getDetails:PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  shopItems: state.shopItems
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getItems }
)(Products);
```

**getDetails.js**

```
import {SHOW_DETAILS} from './types';
import {data} from '../data/data';

export const getDetails = id => dispatch =>{
    const detailProduct = data.find(item => item.id === id)
    dispatch({
        type:SHOW_DETAILS,
        payload:detailProduct
    })
}
```

**detailsReducer.js**

```
import { SHOW_DETAILS } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  detailProduct: {}
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_DETAILS:
      return {
        detailProduct: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**index.js**(root reducer)

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import itemsReducer from './itemsReducer'
import detailsReducer from './detailsReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    shopItems:itemsReducer,
    detailProduct:detailsReducer
})
```

**Store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';


const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

let store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

**I expect:**

1. Connect action `getDetails` to  component `Products.js`.
2. Make `onClick()`  to grab needed **item's id**.
3. Use `find()` item by it's id, **receive item's info in state** `detailProduct`.
4. No errors.

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: @EugeniBejan  
`Error: Invalid value of type object for mergeProps argument when connecting component Products.`

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418964/5721584) you have a possible solution

Comment: @EugeniBejan I tried the solution provided there, it pops **actions undefined**